# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Whenever I enter `"http://localhost:3000/Test"` I get this error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: `<Test />`. Did you accidentally export a JSX
> literal instead of a component?

This is my code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/*' element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route  } from 'react-router-dom';
import Test from './Test';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/Test' Component={<Test />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The `Route` component takes either an `element` prop that is a `React.ReactNode` value, a.k.a. JSX, ***or*** a `Component` prop that is a `React.ComponentType` value, a.k.a. a reference to a React component.

[Route Type declaration](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration)

> ```
> interface RouteObject {
>   path?: string;
>   index?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   id?: string;
>   loader?: LoaderFunction;
>   action?: ActionFunction;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;       // <-- JSX
>   Component?: React.ComponentType | null; // <-- React component reference
>   errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   ErrorBoundary?: React.ComponentType | null;
>   handle?: RouteObject["handle"];
>   shouldRevalidate?: ShouldRevalidateFunction;
>   lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<RouteObject>;
> }
> ```

The `App` component is passing `Test` as JSX to the `Component` prop, which is invald.

```
<Route path='/Test' Component={<Test />} />
```

## Solution

Update the route to use the proper prop types:

Using the `element` prop:

```
<Route path='/Test' element={<Test />} />
```

Using the `Component` prop:

```
<Route path='/Test' Component={Test} />
```

Note however that the `Component` prop is only validly used in Data routers, e.g. routers created using `createBrowserRouter`, etc. See [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) for details.

> You should only opt into the `Component` API for data routes via
> `RouterProvider`. Using this API on a `<Route>` inside `<Routes>` will
> de-optimize React's ability to reuse the created element across
> renders.

In other words, it leads to potentially poorer performance because mounted components are remounted instead of rerendered. Since you are not using a Data router you should use the `element` prop.